# l18n::InvalidLocaleData Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Error occurs when you click on a url http://localhost:3000/articles/new/.

Showing c:/Sites/blog/app/views/articles/new.html.erb where line #8 raised:

can not load translations from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml: expects it to return a hash, but does not

File blog.html.erp

```
 <h1>New article</h1> 


<%= form_for :article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title%><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text%><br>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Controller articles action new.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
end
```

File config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :articles
  get 'welcome/index'
```

Rails 4.1.8
Ruby 2.1.5 
Winddows 7

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of the files C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\activesupport-4.1.8\lib\active_support\locale\en.yml put -  en: